# How can I determine a group of numbers in the middle of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence that has a series of numbers, and on first glance, it doesn't appear to have any set pattern. (I'm using a generic X to signify numbers that I don't know)

27.01, 27.32, 27.68, 28.04, 28.39, X, 29.1, X, 29.82, 30.17, 30.56, X, X, 31.61

This goes on all the way up to 100.00 with sporadic numbers missing from the sequence.

Is there a mathematical way to determine this?

Comment: It will be a lot easier to make useful suggestions if you disclose where the numbers come from and what they mean. That will allow one to make some domain-specific assumptions. In contrast, just saying that it is "a sequence" doesn't constrain the result at all -- if you simply set every $X$ to 0 it will _still_ be "a sequence".

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha fit command](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit%20%5B%5B1%2C27.01%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C27.32%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C27.68%5D%2C%20%5B4%2C28.04%5D%2C%20%5B5%2C28.39%5D%2C%20%20%5B7%2C29.1%5D%2C%20%20%5B9%2C29.82%5D%2C%20%5B10%2C30.17%5D%2C%20%5B11%2C30.56%5D%2C%20%20%5B14%2C31.61%5D%5D) gives nicely-fitting polynomials; quadratic or even linear fit works very  well. I think the sequence may be linear with random fluctuations.

Comment: ... in which case [linear fit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20fit%20%5B%5B1%2C27.01%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C27.32%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C27.68%5D%2C%20%5B4%2C28.04%5D%2C%20%5B5%2C28.39%5D%2C%20%20%5B7%2C29.1%5D%2C%20%20%5B9%2C29.82%5D%2C%20%5B10%2C30.17%5D%2C%20%5B11%2C30.56%5D%2C%20%20%5B14%2C31.61%5D%5D) is the way to go. It gives $a_n=0.35613n+26.6195$, where $n=1,2,\dots$ in the index of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the sequence you posted is increasing, and that the spacing doesn't vary a whole lot (though it isn't constant).

Not knowing anything else about the purpose, a reasonable way to fill in the gaps would be to take the difference of the numbers you know -- say, $d = 29.1 - 28.39 = 0.71$ -- and split it up into $n+1$ equal segments of size $d/(n+1)$, where $n$ is the number of unknown points in between those two values.

You only have the numbers to the hundredths, so round the values to taste.

So, doing it this way, your unknown values would be $28.75, 29.46, 30.91, 31.26.$

Now, if these are values measured at particular times, or measured with respect to some other independent variable, then a least-squares optimization to fill in the gaps will be more rigorous than what I just did.